# Use act_as_list without scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, scope, html-lists

I'm using rails's acts_as_list to order a table:

https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list

However I don't want to use any scope and not have the ordered table linked to any other.

How do I use acts_as_list without any scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding acts_as_list to your model without defining a scope will simply order according to instance creation.

e.g.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_list
```

Also, the scope doesn't need to be a relation, it could simply be a field of the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

ActsAsList have two options for ordering:

- :column, you can specify the column of the class which you want to use, without a parent class
- :scope, using the parent class to use the order

This two options need a 'position' column. And the methods still works equal

```
class Element < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_list :column => 'position'
end
```